# Append an output from external command at the cursor in vim

Tags: vim

Using `:r !command`, append the output to the next line.

Is it possible to append the command output from the cursor in the same line?

Comment: If you have `xclip`, you can type `:r !command|xclip -i`, then simply paste at the cursor. Note that all new-lines will be included in the pasted text.

Comment: @AFH Nice workaround, but I am afraid that is not exactly what I was looking for. I would like to add that it works best when in insert mode before pasting.

Comment: I would expect any added text to honour insert/overwrite mode, whatever mechanism might be used. You can reduce typing by using a script with a single letter (eg `i`) containing `exec xclip -i`, so that you need type only `:r !command|i`.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following mappings for insert and command-line mode:

```
" i_CTRL-R_`        Insert the output of an external command.
" c_CTRL-R_`
function! s:QueryExternalCommand( newlineReplacement )
    call inputsave()
    let l:command = input('$ ', '', 'shellcmd')
    call inputrestore()
    return (empty(l:command) ?
    \   '' :
    \   substitute(substitute(system(l:command), '\n\+$', '', ''), '\n', a:newlineReplacement, 'g')
    \)
endfunction
inoremap <C-r>` <C-g>u<C-r>=<SID>QueryExternalCommand('\r')<CR>
cnoremap <C-r>` <C-r>=<SID>QueryExternalCommand('\\n')<CR>
```